# In mysql how to mysql tuning up?

Tags: mysql

What is uses of long_query_time?

i want to improve performance, so i change long_query_time= 10 to 5,
what exactly it will do?
if my query takes more than 5 seconds to retrieve records from db is there any problem or not

Comment: It will consider queries that run for 5 seconds or more as slow. It won't TUNE anything. If it was that easy to tune stuff, why even have that option? It would be 0 by default.

Answer (score 0):

It will generate the log of query which takes the more than 10 seconds. And that indicates that you need more optimize query. This doesn't affect any thing just create log and help you to improve  optimization

Comment: thanks, can u let me know path for this log, i mean where that log file path

Comment: To see the log file path you need to see my.ini file which you can find under "mysql/bin" and find "general_log_file" word. In this var the path of the log file is assigned. You can also change if you want

Answer (score 0):

N.B. is right. Theres a slow_query_log that saves all processed queries that are above the long_query_time.

For speeding up a mysql database the first good thing would be setting up good indexes on your tables.

Check [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-index.html) reference.